# Joining two tables on colums with dissimilar (but connected) values

Tags: sql

How can I connect two tables on columns with certain linked values but not having the same values?

For instance I need to join `tbl1` to `tbl2` where `tbl1.col=100` and `tbl2.col=200`. The only connection that have is to me/my company.

Is there a way to link the rows without an explicit shared value? I need all rows with col value '100' to be on the same row as all tbl2 columns have col value 200.

Comment: Can you clarify your question to define what "connected" means?  Do the two tables have a common foreign key between them?

Comment: No, the tables do not have an explicit common key. They have ids that I know are linked but is not stored in the table. It is stupid I know but I do not have the option to fix it, only to work with it.

Comment: Give a simple example showing two tables (column names and a few rows) and then show an example illustrating what you want done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to link the rows without an explicit shared value?

**Yes**. You can write a custom `JOIN` to relate data yourself.

You didn't specify your specific DBMS, so the following examples contain generic SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE tbl1.col = 100 AND tbl12.col = 200
```

Or, more dynamically:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE tbl1.col + 100 = tbl12.col;
-- with JOIN
SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ON (tbl1.col + 100) = tbl12.col;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put some logic in your join predicate, as in:

```
select *
from tbl1 as a
    join tbl2 as b on a.col + 100 = b.col
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  *
from
  tbl1
    inner join
  tbl2
    on tbl1.col = 100 and tbl2.col = 200
```

weird, but it will work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have two tables that logically relate to each other but the current keys in the tables don't (but you have business rules that put them together).  I think you need to create a cross-reference table that maps that relationship.  The cross-reference table would map the primary keys of each other tables together to show the logical relationship between the data.

I think all of the others posters have made the assumption that the relationship is one you can calculate, but I don't think that is what you are asking.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Right, I cannot calculate the value. Is there a way to do this without creating a cross-reference table? It might be beyond my permissions to create something like that.

Comment: How many records are you trying to query?  Like the other posters mentioned, you can create a custom predicate in the JOIN or WHERE clause from within an application.  The primary downfall of this is that it would be terribly inefficient for large queries.  I would make certain creating a cross-reference table is not an option as that is the best design for what you are trying to do.  Otherwise, you'll have to create custom WHERE clauses or JOIN conditions in the application that uses the database.